# Bumpy ride. Is it the casing or the inner tube?

Tags: tire, innertube

I pumped a new tube to about 80 psi (I missed that on the casing the recommended pressure is 100 psi). On the ride immediatly, I hit a very small kerb harder than I wished and after I noticed that my ride was bumpier than usual (though I couldnt say for sure if it's because of the kerb). Upon visual inspection, I notice that the casing doesn't go perfectly round (between the lowest point and the highest there seems to be maybe a 3-4 mm difference). The inner rim seems round enough but the whole wheel (back wheel) seems a bit wobbly.

I think it's not the rim that has issues. How can I check if I need to change the casing or the inner tube?

Thank you.

Comment: @Blam fixed. Sorry not used to imperial units.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What could cause an inflated tire to be "untrue" on a true rim](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/24680/what-could-cause-an-inflated-tire-to-be-untrue-on-a-true-rim)

Comment: Whole back wheel seems wobbly? If the wheel itself is wobbling, it is either not seated in the dropouts correctly, or you've got other problems which require you to take the wheel to a bike shop such as an untrue rim or something else.

Comment: Hi OP - this question is old, and has no answer.  Would you like to post and accept your own new answer describing how it has gone for you in the past 11 months?  What did you do to fix the bumpity wheel?

Comment: @Criggie Sorry. Well I still had a warranty on my wheels so I've changed them. They stopped being true I think. When rolled at high speed the wheel (without tubbing and tire) was very unstable. So what could I do with this question?

Comment: Take it back to the bike shop (or a different one).  Your descriptions are not sufficiently detailed for us to make a diagnosis from here.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you're talking about a vertical bump rather than lateral wobble. This can happen if the tyre hasn't been fitted correctly and isn't sitting properly around the valve area, especially if you have the locknut at the base of the valve stem. It's easily fixed with a bit of fiddling, but it's not something that would likely be caused by an impact.

Comment: @user814425 I had removed the tire and rolled the wheel. At higher speeds it would give quite a kick (in the vertical axis). I never found out what the problem was since the shop took the wheels back when they fitted the new ones. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP said:

> Well I still had a warranty on my wheels so I've changed them. They
>   stopped being true I think. When rolled at high speed the wheel
>   (without tubbing and tire) was very unstable.

Hooray for warranties!  Remember, always keep your receipts, and don't procrastinate or the warranty window may close on you.